# Scanning project directories android studio

Tags: android-studio

When I open my `Android Studio 2.1.2` it performs `Scanning project directories...` background task infinitely and I cannot check through my code. This has not happened before as I have been using the studio for quite a while without the prob and I have not changed any files. I have tried restarting the studio severally but it doesn't help and have also checked the internet but it only offers solutions for `Scanning files to index...` infinite background task. So what might be the prob and how can i fix it??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to actually fix but a workaround would be to go to File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart option. 
That usually seals the deal for me when Android Studio is stuck Scanning directories or indexing.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Workarounds that don't really answer the question are best left in the comment section than in an answer. [You'll be able to comment when your reputation is 50](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Meanwhile, please don't use answers instead.